# Implementing an interface without an interface type parameter

Tags: java, apache-storm

Apache Storm has an interface [IBasicBolt](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/javadocs/org/apache/storm/topology/IBasicBolt.html) with an untyped Map.

```
//org.apache.storm.topology.IBasicBolt
public interface IBasicBolt extends IComponent {
    void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context);
    ...
}
```

I want to add a typed Map in my abstract class,

```
public abstract class MyClass implements IBasicBolt {
    @override
    public void prepare(Map<String, Object> stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without adding `<String, Object>` to the storm class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is appropriate for this type of situation, although in your use case may not be entirely what you are after. But it's a pattern worth knowing about and may steer you in the right direction.

**Intent**

Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompataible interfaces.

**Example**

So consider the target interface, i.e. the one you wish to program to:

```
public interface IMyBasicBolt {    
    void prepare(Map<String, Object> stormConf, String other);    
}
```

(Note: I have replaced `TopologyContext` with `String` for simplicity)

You can then create an adapter class which implements your target interface and delegates the behaviour (composition) to an implementation of `IBoltBasic`.

```
public class BasicBoltAdapter implements IMyBasicBolt {

    private IBasicBolt basicBolt;

    public BasicBoltAdapter(IBasicBolt basicBolt) {
        this.basicBolt = basicBolt;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map<String, Object> stormConf, String other) {
        basicBolt.prepare(stormConf, other);
    }    

}
```

Example use of the Adapter `BasicBoltAdapter`:

```
IBasicBolt basicBolt = new IBasicBolt() {

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, String other) {
        System.out.println(stormConf.toString() + " " + other);
    }
};
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("MapKeyTest", new Object());
IMyBasicBolt myBasicBolt = new BasicBoltAdapter(basicBolt);
myBasicBolt.prepare(map, "Test");
```

There isn't strictly a need for the interface `IMyBasicBolt` (your target interface) in your case. But it's generally good to program to an interface where possible.